# "TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, python-2.x, abstract-methods

I have a module `fi` with the following classes defined:

```
class Asset(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_price(self, dt : datetime.date, **kwargs):
    ''' Nothing here yet
    '''

class CashFlows(Asset):

   def __init__(self, amounts : pandas.Series, probabilities : pandas.Series = None):
   amounts = Asset.to_cash_flows()
```

I then have another class `Bond(fi.Asset)` with this method within it:

```
def to_cash_flows(self, notional : float = 100.0) -> fi.asset.CashFlows:
    series = pandas.Series(list_of_data, indices_of_data)
    return fi.CashFlows(series)
```

I get the error `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class CashFlows with abstract methods get_price` when I call `to_cash_flows`. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086826/cant-instantiate-abstract-class-with-abstract-methods-on-class-that-shouldn), but am unable to relate it with my current issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `CashFlows` class needs to define an implementation of `get_price`; it's an abstract method and concrete subclasses **must** implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override **`get_price()` abstract method** in **`CashFlows` class** as shown below:

```py
class Asset(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_price(self, dt : datetime.date, **kwargs):
        pass

class CashFlows(Asset):

    def __init__(
        self, 
        amounts : pandas.Series, 
        probabilities : pandas.Series = None
    ):
        amounts = Asset.to_cash_flows()
    
    # You need to override
    def get_price(self, dt : datetime.date, **kwargs):
        return "Hello"
```